# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [11097, 1233]

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, python-3.6

I'm trying to create a trading website and use sklearn to recognise patterns in trades in python 3.6.
I get the data from the website like so:

```
buyer = "FORM54"
getBuyer = requests.get("https://url.com/buyer=%s/" % buyer)
```

Then use pandas to get the data i need:

```
data = pd.read_json(StringIO(getBuyer.text))
data = data[["strike_price", "underlying_price", "notional_amount", "quantity"]]
```

and try to predict the quantity of trades like so:

```
predict = "quantity"
X = np.array(data.drop([predict],1))
y = np.array(data[predict])

x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size =  0.1)
```

However i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP Omen/PycharmProjects/untitled2/main.py", line 31, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\HP Omen\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_base.py", line 1130, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, "csr", multi_output=True)
  File "C:\Users\HP Omen\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 765, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "C:\Users\HP Omen\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 212, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [11097, 1233]
```

This is the X and y shapes:

```
>>> X.shape
(12330, 3)
>>> y.shape
(12330,)
```

However it changes when `buyer` changes

Comment: you need to show the full code, including the line that produces the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size =  0.1)
```

and see if it resolves your problem.

Comment: Check the docs for [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). The correct ordering is `x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test`